# appendBytes() not working on actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, netstream

I have the  following code

```
var playingStream:NetStream;
function playBytes(bytes:ByteArray): void
{

            var connect_nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
        connect_nc.connect(null);
            playingStream=new NetStream(connect_nc);
            playingStream.soundTransform= mySound;
             playingStream.play(null);
            playingStream.appendBytes(bytes);
}
```

I am calling this function from JS using the external interface callback
But as soon as I compile the above code in the `.fla` file, it throws an error.

Error:1061 Call to a possibly undefined method appendBytes through a reference with static type flash.net:NetStream

The flash [help page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#appendBytes%28%29) shows that the function is valid in AS3 . Where am I going wring then ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have should work however, the appendBytes method was included in Flash Player 10.1 and newer. If you are compiling against anything lower then 10.1, you would get an error similar to the one listed in your question.  Check out the following blog post at ByteArray.org, and the example I've included below.  I built the example for a different post and I hope it helps you out as well!

[AppendBytes](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1689)

---

Playback Initialization:

```
var video:Video = new Video(width, height);
var video_nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
var video_ns:NetStream = new NetStream();

video_nc.connect(null);
video_ns.play(null);
video_ns.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN);

video.attachNetStream(video_ns);
```

ProgressEvent.PROGRESS Handler:

```
video_ns.appendBytes(bytesAvailable);
```

This is essentially the jist of it, bytesAvailable will represent the read bytes from the event data buffer.  A full example is listed below:

```
package
{

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.net.NetStream;
import flash.net.NetStreamAppendBytesAction;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLStream;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

[SWF(width="1280", height="720")]
public class NetStreamAppendBytes extends Sprite
{

    var video:Video;
    var video_nc:NetConnection;
    var video_ns:NetStream;

    var video_stream:URLStream; 

    public function NetStreamAppendBytes()
    {
        super();

        video_nc = new NetConnection();
        video_nc.connect(null);

        video_ns = new NetStream(video_nc);
        video_ns.client = this;
        video_ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, ns_statusHandler);

        video = new Video(1280, 720);
        video.attachNetStream(video_ns);
        video.smoothing = true;

        video_ns.play(null);
        video_ns.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN);

        video_stream = new URLStream();
        video_stream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, videoStream_progressHandler);

        video_stream.load(new URLRequest("path_to_flv"));

        addChild(video);
    }

    private function ns_statusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void
    {
        trace(event.info.code);
    }

    private function videoStream_progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
    {
        var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

        video_stream.readBytes(bytes);
        video_ns.appendBytes(bytes);
    }

}

}
```

Best of luck!

Comment: If you are encoding a persistent black frame into an flv, you could use this technique to http stream aac/m4a.  My test flv is encoded with H264 and aac/mp4a.  Check out this link for more information regarding http psudostreaming. http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12534/video-delivery-http-pseudo-streaming

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the code at first glance, but on the help page it has a note:

> This method is not supported for H.264 video in AIR 3.0 for iOS

are you deploying this on an iphone, or with adobe air?